# Can I further reduce dependency on docker images to run by asp.net web api application on docker container

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, asp.net-web-api, containers

I followed https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker link to build my sample ASP.NET Web API application build on top on .net 4.6.1 framework.

Here is my docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.sln .
COPY TestWebAPI/*.csproj ./TestWebAPI/
COPY TestWebAPI/*.config ./TestWebAPI/
RUN nuget restore

# copy everything else and build app
COPY TestWebAPI/. ./TestWebAPI/
WORKDIR /app/TestWebAPI
RUN msbuild /p:Configuration=Release


FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2 AS runtime
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY --from=build /app/TestWebAPI/. ./
```

**To run the script I executed following commands:**

```
docker image build --tag testwebapi --file .\Dockerfile .

docker container run --detach --publish 80 testwebapi
```

**The script is working fine and I am able to run my application.**

**Questions:**

1. I am using `dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk` image to build & `aspnet:4.7.2` image to run the application. I looked at the aspnet image and it contains  "Windows Server Core as the base OS, IIS 10 as Web Server, .NET Framework (multiple versions available),.NET Extensibility for IIS". In this case do I still need `dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk` image ?

   [image]
2. I don't think the script is using IIS as the web server. How can I use IIS to host this application?

Comment: You need the SDK to compile it, but not to run it.

Comment: @SLaks: I could be wrong but the aspnet image also contains the .net framework. I assume it should also have MSBuild.exe to build the application.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the sdk base image is not actually included in your final image, only the runtime image is. There are two `FROM` lines in your `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk AS build
...
FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2 AS runtime
```

This creates a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build). Only the base image of the second (last) stage, which is the runtime image, will be included in your image.

For what's included in the sdk image beyond the .NET Framework itself, take a look at its [Dockerfile](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/master/4.7.2/sdk/windowsservercore-ltsc2016/Dockerfile) and you'll spot a few things you definitely won't need on your production servers, such as NuGet CLI, VS Test Agent etc.

Comment: I looked at the other dockerfile mentioned in your answer. Looking at this dockerfile, it looks like my dockerfile is already pretty lean and this container can run in production. Am i missing something? Also with Multistage build, I don't have to worry about sdk image being added to my container.

Comment: Can you answer my second question,  how can i Utilize IIS ?